# Visual Studio Multi Device Hybrid App how to add intent-filter to AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, plugins, android-manifest

I’m trying to add an intent-filter to the AndroidManifest.xml file, however I think this file is generated as part of the build process. So where would I add this and to which file.

This is what I need to add to get added to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <data android:mimeType="my/mimetype" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the intent-filter in a Cordova application, you will need to use a custom plugin that can handle this code.

The Cordova [WebIntent plugin](https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent) should be easy enough to use.

To include the plugin in your Multi-device Hybrid Apps project, open your config.xml file and then add an entry:

```
<vs:feature>link_to_github_repo_here</vs:feature>
```

OR

Create a folder called "plugins" in your project root and paste the downloaded plugin into the folder.

Comment: Thanks, where would I add the code to add the intent above?

Comment: Any idea where to add the APP_ID or APP_NAME values for the facebookConnect plugin??